# Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand parameter passing suddenly fails

Tags: azure, powershell, parameter-passing, remote-access, azure-automation

**Context:** Running an Azure Automation Account solution where a caller PS script executes another PS script (executed on a VM) with parameter passing via 'Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand'.

**Story:** I had running a PowerShell (caller) script that executed another (called) PowerShell script on a remote Azure Win VM. That flow ran via an Automation Account schedule every day but suddenly stopped working two days ago because the parameter passing from the caller to the called script is not working anymore. I currently blame the MSFT Azure people for breaking my PRD solution.

Here the caller PS script code for the arguments to pass on:

```
$hshParams = @{
    strSAName         = $hshParameters.strStagingSA
    strSAAccessKey    = $strSAAccessKey
    strFileShare      = '"' + $strFileShare + '"'
    strCopyObjects    = $hshParameters.strCopyObjects
    strSrcDriveLetter = $strSrcDriveLetter
    strDstDriveLetter = $strDstDriveLetter
}
```

Here the invocaton of the VM-run PS script:

```
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $objVM.ResourceGroupName -Name $objVM.Name `
    -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $strRemoteScriptFileNameTmp -Parameter $hshParams
```

Here the parameter reception code on the VM-run PS script side:

```
# Parameters
Param (
    [string] $strCopyObjects = $null,
    [string] $strSAAccessKey = $null,
    [string] $strFileShare = $null,
    [string] $strSAName = $null,
    [string] $strDstDriveLetter = $null,
    [string] $strSrcDriveLetter = $null
)
```

Until two days ago all those six string values were populated properly and according to the argument setup in the hash table '$hshParams':

```
$strSAAccessKey = 92LO1Q4tuyeiqxxx
$strFileShare = 129xxxa1.file.core.windows.net\solutionfiles
$strSAName = 12xsa1
$strDstDriveLetter = D
$strSrcDriveLetter = Z
$strCopyObjects = AutoTopUp\Application\Live
```

**Problem:** Now I see five string values suddenly not being populated anymore with one being garbage, here is what they look like today:

```
$strSAAccessKey = []
$strFileShare = []
$strSAName = []
$strDstDriveLetter = []
$strSrcDriveLetter = []
$strCopyObjects = AutoTopUp\Application\Live" -strSAAccessKey 92LO1Q4tuyeiqxxx -strFileShare 129xxxa1.file.core.windows.net\solutionfiles -strSAName 12xsa1 -strDstDriveLetter D -strSrcDriveLetter Z
```

The solution was not touched, it just had been running as per schedule. $Args.Count on the VM-run script returns '2'.

**My Question:** Anyone with an explanation on this new behaviour? Frustratingly, I did not manage to arrange the parameter passing in a different way as it is all a bit unclear what the proper way of receiving the hash table values would be. The MSFT help page for 'Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand' is (of course) not helping here, also did I not find any other clear ways on the parameter passing on SO or Google...

Comment: why is it not clear. it clearly says `hashtable` and the example shows: `-Parameter @{"arg1" = "var1";"arg2" = "var2"}`. I suggest you print the hashtable before calling the cmdlet or debug your script to find out what is going wrong

Comment: "Not clear" refers to how to pull the values in the receiver script, there is never a word about that as everybody only copy/pasts that MSFT example line as you did. And yes, I do excactly that debugging work  - the results are part of my post. Do you have more on my question, content-wise?

Comment: Outcome of further debugging efforts: Output of $Args.Count on the VM-run script returns '2' where $Args(0) is "-strCopyObjects", and  $Args(1) is that long string in '$strCopyObjects' above. Also note that single double quote hanging in there.

Answer (score 0):

Related question is raised in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/152550f3-753b-475a-a8af-82490a3ab734/invokeazurermvmruncommand-parameter-passing-suddenly-fails?forum=azureautomation) MSDN thread; Just sharing this for the benefit of broader audience who might face similar issue.